# What's written behind the makeshift club sign?

Tags: japanese-language, gakkou-gurashi

I don't know if you answer these type of questions, but it would help if you could answer this. Japanese schools have signs outside their rooms. For example, there's 資料室 for "resource room". In the first episode of Gakkou Gurashi!, the opening sequence shows a sign that is covered with a piece of paper by the words "学園生活部". This anime is apparently extremely misleading in its content, and I was wondering whether the words behind it were a reference to something in the anime. Do you know if you can figure out what the words might be?

The picture is attached below:

[image: sign]

Comment: How is this a language question?  I can read the "original" sign effortlessly, but why it was replaced by 「学園生活部」 is not a language question.  It is an anime question.

Answer (score 4):

The original sign is 生徒会室 *seitokai-shitsu* "student council room".

I haven't read the manga, so I can only presume that their club has co-opted what was formerly the student council office as their headquarters for some reason.

(I guess this is something of a tip-off to the episode 1 twist - it's weird that another club would just up and occupy the student council office, after all.)

Comment: As if the "Tastes like Survival" quote from the pasta breakfast was not enough... XD